# JAXB - Java Enums without XSD enumerations

Tags: java, jaxb

I have a XSD with a type like this:

```
<xsd:simpleType name="status">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
      <xsd:pattern value="(open|closed)"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
  </xsd:simpleType>
```

Is there a way of generating a Java Enum out of this? Unfortunately `typesafeEnumClass` only works as [Only simpleType definitions with enumeration facets can be customized using this binding declaration.](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.5/tutorial/doc/JAXBUsing4.html)

I know I can bind this to a Java type like this:

```
<jaxb:bindings node="//xsd:simpleType [@name='status']">
        <jaxb:javaType
            name="package.ImplType"
            parseMethod="package.ImplConv.parseStringToEnum"
            printMethod="package.ImplConv.printEnumToString"/>
    </jaxb:bindings>
```

But this does not work for me for other reasons.

I am just trying to leave the XSD unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

Write your own class `Status` and customize your simple type `status` to be mapped using that class:

```
    <jaxb:bindings node="xs:simpleType[@name='status']">
        <jaxb:typesafeEnumClass ref="Status"/>
    </jaxb:bindings>
```

In this case, XJC will use the `Status` class for the `status` simple type.

As far as I can tell from the source code, the check for "typesafe-enum-capable" schema structures is hardcoded.